# Rotate each context via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

```
image = new Image();
image.src = 'assets/img/image.png';
for (var i = 0; i < this.bombs.length; i++) {
  var bomb = this.bombs[i];
  ctx.drawImage(image, bomb.x - 2, bomb.y - 2, 15, 8);

}
```

This is an image in my canvas game and falling down from top. But I want, get images rotate random each state.

I tried this:

```
function drawRotated(degrees){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
    ctx.rotate(degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(image,-image.width/2,-image.width/2);
    ctx.restore();
}
```

Added this function in my image but its not working. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track!

To rotate one (or more) images:

1. Translate to the center point where you want the image centered.
2. Rotate by the desired angle
3. Draw the image
4. Undo the transformations (undo translate & rotate).

**A couple of changes:**

- You always `translate` to the middle of the canvas. If you want the bomb to drop you must increasingly translate down the canvas.
- A typo: In `drawImage` you have used `width` for both the width & height argument.
- An efficiency: `context.save and context.restore` are more expensive operations because they save & restore all of the canvas styles. Instead, it's more efficient to reset only your transformations (translate,rotate) with `context.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)`

**Here's your code refactored for these changes:**

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var bomb;

var img=new Image();
img.onload=start;
img.src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/139992952/multple/danger.png";
function start(){
    var aa=img.width*img.width;
    var bb=img.height*img.height;
    var cc=Math.sqrt(aa+bb);
    bomb={
        x:150,y:-img.height/2,
        degrees:0,image:img,
        maxRotatedHalfHeight:cc/2
    };
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

function drawRotated(b){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height);
    ctx.save();
    ctx.translate(b.x,b.y);
    ctx.rotate(b.degrees*Math.PI/180);
    ctx.drawImage(b.image,-b.image.width/2,-b.image.height/2);
    ctx.restore();
}

function animate(time){
    drawRotated(bomb);
    bomb.y+=1;
    bomb.degrees+=1;
    if(bomb.y<=canvas.height+bomb.maxRotatedHalfHeight){
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    }else{
            alert('Animation is complete.');
    }
}
```

```css
body{ background-color: ivory; }
#canvas{border:1px solid red; margin:0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=175></canvas>
```